# Restricting use for 5 minutes

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, xhtml

I am planning on creating a small website with JavaEE where a user can vote but only every 5 minutes. There are two buttons. One to vote yes and the other to vote no. I want the buttons to only be clickable every 5 minutes. Whats the best way to do this?

I thought of getting the users IP and entering it into my DB along with the timestamp. Everytime a user would vote I would get their IP from the DB and check if 5 mins have passed since their last vote. What do you think of this solution? Is this best practise?

I am trying to avoid a login or any other sort of authentication.
I plan on using JSF, Java, mySQL and AJAX.

Comment: What you tried to achieve this? Any Idea,thought? Which technology you are going to use?

Comment: What about 50,000 people connecting via a proxy server (all on the same IP address as far as your site is concerned)? You can only really do this sort of thing in the context of a login. You could authenticate using Google or Facebook, like this site does.

Comment: Storing cookies may be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be a cookie containing the last date of vote in client side **plus** saving the user IP and date of vote in a datatabse in server side.

If there is no cookie in client side and if there is zero entry in your database containing the user's IP address, or if the date stored in this enty is inferior to your vote recover time, then the user can vote.

Keep in mind that the more people will click your buttons, the more request your server will have to handle.

There is no risk zero, but you can get close to it.

Comment: ofc, this is why you use cookies + store ip address in base.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is by creating a simple log in. I don't see any other way around it that is 99.9% safe.

Comment: Yes you're right about the safeness. Thought, a login may discourage users :/